# selector for looping through nested array ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

In order to access the items array from this JSON, how should I use a selector?

```
const list  = {
        "nestedService": [
            {
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "name": "test1",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "itemCat": [
                                    {
                                        "code": "123"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test2",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "itemCat": [
                                    {
                                        "code": "345"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

The following is what I tried to get nestedServices for the list, I needed help in fetching items

```
export const getItems =
createSelector(selectState,(state) =>  {
      const data = state.list
      return data?.map(e => e.nestedService);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`list` is an object, so using `map` is a mistake. Using a `selector` for grabbing what you exactly need from the store is the right choice.

Just return the exact property you want:

```js
// this will return the wanted array
export const getItems = createSelector(
   selectState,
   (state) =>  state.list['nestedService']);
```